# How to get data from javascript array object / JSON and use it in React JS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am developing a React Js website. Where I have a form with 4 select fields Make, Model, Min price and Max price. I have a javascript file which contains make and models of cars.
File contains multiple Car Makes. File data is available below which represent Car Make and its available models in array.

```
export const veh_data = [{"alfa-romeo": ["145", "90", "Alfa 6", "Alfasud"]},
{"aston-martin": ["15", "2-Litre", "AM Vantage", "Atom", "Cygnet", "DB2"]},
{"audi": ["100", "200", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7" ]}
];
```

I want to get that data (Make name (e.g audi) and its Models) from this file and display that data as options of Select fields in the form.

Here is my React JS component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, FormGroup, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import { veh_data } from '../shared/vehicle_make_and_models'

class ImgAndForm extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        veh_data: veh_data,
    };

}

handleSearch(event) {
    alert("Search button clicked");
    event.preventDefault();

}

render() {

    const veh_make = this.state.veh_data.map((veh) => {
        return (
          <div>
              <option></option>
          </div>
        );
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <header className="headerbg d-flex">
                <div className="container my-auto">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="offset-1 col-10 offset-lg-0 col-lg-4">
                            <div id="search-form-div" className="container">
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-12 my-4">
                                        <h3>Search</h3>
                                        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSearch}>
                                            <FormGroup>
                                                <Input type="select" name="select1" id="select1">
                                                    <option value="">Make</option>
                                                    {veh_make}
                                                </Input>
                                            </FormGroup>
                                            <FormGroup>
                                                <Input type="select" name="select2" id="select2">
                                                    <option value="">Model</option>
                                                    {veh_make}
                                                </Input>
                                            </FormGroup>
                                            <FormGroup>
                                                <Input type="select" name="select3" id="select3">
                                                    <option value="">Min Price</option>
                                                    <option value="500">500</option>
                                                </Input>
                                            </FormGroup>
                                            <FormGroup>
                                                <Input type="select" name="select4" id="select4">
                                                    <option value="">Max Price</option>
                                                    <option value="2000">2000</option>
                                                </Input>
                                            </FormGroup>
                                            <FormGroup>
                                                <Input type="submit" name="search" id="search" className="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
                                            </FormGroup>
                                        </Form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>

        </div>
    );
}
}

export default ImgAndForm;
```

Comment: OP: these things are pretty easy to debug: just `console.log(veh_data)`. Does it give you what you expect? Go from there.

Comment: could you please provide a solution to solve my problem?

Comment: Actually I want to use that data in my form select fields. don't know how to use in my react app

Comment: there is no problem in importing data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to parse the vehicle values into separate arrays of JSX options elements. I prefer to do this with a reduce function...

```
const vehicles = this.state.veh_data.reduce((acc, veh) => {
      let make = Object.keys(veh)[0],
          vehModels = veh[make];

      return {
            makes: [
                  ...acc.makes,
                  <option value={make}>{make}</option>
            ],
            models:[
                  ...acc.models,
                  ...vehModels.map(model => {
                       return <option value={model}>{model}</option>
                  })
            ]  
       };
},{makes:[], models:[]});
```

Since each element in your veh_data array is an object you need to access its first (and only) property with Object.keys() to get all keys of the object, then just grab the first (and only) key.

Model can be access by getting the value of that key in each veh object you're iterating over

...

```
<FormGroup>
      <Input type="select" name="select1" id="select1">
      <option selected disabled>Make</option>
      {vehicles.makes}
      </Input>
</FormGroup>
```

...

```
<FormGroup>
  <Input type="select" name="select2" id="select2">
        <option selected disabled>Model</option>
        {vehicles.models}
  </Input>
</FormGroup>
```

...

Given the context I also don't see a need to store the veh_data to the component state, which is a waste of resources unless that data will be updating the UI dynamically so this would be the complete solution....

https://jsfiddle.net/mfpv1L6s/

(NOTE: I understand this won't give you the full solution you 'should' be looking for as it will show the model options for every vehicle rather than the only the models related to the currently selected 'make', but this should be a good starting point for you.)

EXTRA CREDIT: I'd also parse out the option presentation values to something a little more attractive like this...

```
keyToOption(key){
        return key.split('-')
                .map(word=> word.slice(0,1).toUpperCase + word.slice(1))
                .join(' ');
 }
```

Then add it to the reduce function like this...

```
makes: [
    ...acc.makes,
    <option value={make}>{this.keyToOption(make)}</option>
],
```

I've included the above in the JSFiddle

(Complete working example....)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Form, FormGroup, Input } from "reactstrap";
// import { veh_data } from '../shared/vehicle_make_and_models'
const veh_data = [
  { "alfa-romeo": ["145", "90", "Alfa 6", "Alfasud"] },
  { "aston-martin": ["15", "2-Litre", "AM Vantage", "Atom", "Cygnet", "DB2"] },
  { audi: ["100", "200", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7"] }
];

const vehicles = parseVehicleList(veh_data)

class ImgAndForm extends Component { 
  state = { modelSelected: null };

  handleSearch(event) {
    alert("Search button clicked");
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  handleModelChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({ modelSelected: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const selectedModels =
      this.state.modelSelected && this.state.modelSelected.length ? (
        vehicles.models[this.state.modelSelected]
      ) : (
        <option value="">(Please Select Make)</option>
      );

    return (
      <div>
        <header className="headerbg d-flex">
          <div className="container my-auto">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="offset-1 col-10 offset-lg-0 col-lg-4">
                <div id="search-form-div" className="container">
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12 my-4">
                      <h3>Search</h3>
                      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSearch}>
                        <FormGroup>
                          <Input
                            onChange={e => this.handleModelChange(e)}
                            type="select"
                            name="select1"
                            id="select1"
                          >
                            <option value="">Make</option>
                            {vehicles.makes}
                          </Input>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup>
                          <Input type="select" name="select2" id="select2">
                            {selectedModels}
                          </Input>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup>
                          <Input type="select" name="select3" id="select3">
                            <option value="">Min Price</option>
                            <option value="500">500</option>
                          </Input>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup>
                          <Input type="select" name="select4" id="select4">
                            <option value="">Max Price</option>
                            <option value="2000">2000</option>
                          </Input>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup>
                          <Input
                            type="submit"
                            name="search"
                            id="search"
                            className="btn btn-primary"
                            value="Search"
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ImgAndForm;

function parseVehicleList(data) {
  return data.reduce(
    (acc, veh, i) => {
      let make = Object.keys(veh)[0],
        vehModels = veh[make];

      return {
        makes: [
          ...acc.makes,
          <option key={make + i} value={make}>
            {keyToOption(make)}
          </option>
        ],
        models: {
          ...acc.models,
          [make]: vehModels.map((model, i) => {
            return (
              <option key={make + model + i} value={model}>
                {keyToOption(model)}
              </option>
            );
          })
        }
      };
    },
    { makes: [], models: {} }
  );
}

function keyToOption(key) {
  return key
    .split("-")
    .map(word => word.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
    .join(" ");
}
```

Comment: Code is working but there are some mistakes. Please see the screenshot of my web page [screenshot 1](https://imgur.com/a/JANSxKn). There is text "undefined" before each vehicle make name. Also the model select field is showing single array of models instead of separate models like vehicle make name. [screenshot 2](https://imgur.com/a/n605bsA). Could you please solve that?

Comment: Oops, first issue with the 'undefined' is fixed. Just a silly typo, keyToOption() should use 'slice' on the strings not 'split'; thats not even a built in string function

Comment: Full example with stateful Model select here...

https://codesandbox.io/s/4r5p62o7x7?moduleview=1

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. It works fine. I have one more question which is similar to that one. Could you please answer? Here is the link to [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54284062/how-to-fetch-data-from-api-for-multiple-items-in-react-js-component)

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look.